# Refactoring a switch with object initialization

Tags: java, groovy, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor some(java)code with this kind of switch expression:

```
protected Type soSomething(Object param1, Object param2, Object param3) {
   switch (param1) {
      case A: 
         return new TypeA(param1, param2, param3);
      case B: 
         return new TypeB(param1, param2, param3);
      .......
   .... 
...
```

Usually, I use a dictionary to do this kind of refactoring

```
Map map = [
   A : valueA
   B : valueB
   .... 
]



return map[param1]
```

My problem is that i need a NEW instance of the type.
Any idea?

Comment: What's wrong with a `switch` statement? The other way has to construct the entire map, before using just a single value, so it's way less efficient, and can be entirely wrong if the class constructors have side effects.

Comment: so, you say that iyou don't se necessary a refactoring. Normally I don't like the big switch or if/else code blocks

Comment: I say *don't* refactor. A `switch` statement that only executes the relevant `case` is *much* better than constructing a one-use map and doing a map lookup. If you've been refactoring switch statements to maps, I'd say: Go refactor them back.

Comment: @Andreas A Map/dictionary based solution is surely not always the right thing to do. And a one-use map is also not as good. But if the map is some static data in the class and there are many cases, then I think this kind of solution can help a lot. In the end it depends on the preferences of the people working with that code.

Comment: Maybe the tim_yates approach is the best for me, but reading the comments, I have to re-think in refactor it. A map/dictionary is a perfect (for me) solution for static values (as blackdrag says), buy maybe for this kind of solution is better to keep the switch. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to go with your map idea, but store the Types as values:

```
 Map map = [
   A : TypeA,
   B : TypeB,
   .... 
]
```

Then you can easily do this:

```
return map[param1].newInstance(param1, param2, param3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea blackdrag. Then, you say to implement a constructor in each Type?

Comment: Thank you for the idea blackdrag. Then, you say to implement a constructor in each Type? Using an interface too?

Comment: Interface no, constructor yes. we can answer questions based on the information you give. Your question suggested that they already have a constructor like this. If that is not the case, then we need more details... and most probably a different question and approach. Tim's Closure based solution is more flexible in that it can be adapted to handle the parameters different. Most probably a solution would go in that direction then. If that is then still a good refactoring is again something else.

Comment: blackdrag it's something that i thought, but I need to do changes in the types, and they are a lot!

Comment: Then you have still multiple choices... you could make a bunch method, each which will crate the object (can be the constructor directly of course) and use a MethodClosure or maybe a generic invocation mechanism like foo."$method"(param1,param2,param3), where method is the method name that will create the object as String and a map for associating A/B with the name.... or you use Tim's solution... Or of course, you just stay with the switch-case

Answer (score 2):

Or you could have a map of param->Closure

```
Map map = [
   A : {param1, param2, param3 -> new TypeA(param1, param2, param3)},
   B : {param1, param2, param3 -> new TypeB(param1, param2, param3)},
   .... 
]
```

Then;

```
return map[param1](param1, param2, param3)
```

Comment: tim_yates, you say it using java 8, don't?

Comment: sorry, java 8 or groovy

Comment: Not sure what you mean... That's Groovy

Comment: tim_yates I think that it's the best approach to I want